# Angular2: Make route paths case insensitive

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have the following routing configuration.

```
@RouteConfig([
    {
        path: '/home',
        name: 'Homepage',
        component: HomepageComponent,
        useAsDefault: true
    }
)
export class AppComponent {
}
```

whenever the browser is pointed to `/home` this route works but not for `/Home` or any other case variations. How can I make the router to route to the component without caring the case.

thanks

Comment: Do you know if there is an open issue on this? Seems like this should be baked into the new router. The angular 1 router had caseInsensitiveMatch=true.

Answer (score 51):

Here's what I did.

```
import { DefaultUrlSerializer, UrlTree } from '@angular/router';

export class LowerCaseUrlSerializer extends DefaultUrlSerializer {
    parse(url: string): UrlTree {
        // Optional Step: Do some stuff with the url if needed.

        // If you lower it in the optional step 
        // you don't need to use "toLowerCase" 
        // when you pass it down to the next function
        return super.parse(url.toLowerCase()); 
    }
}
```

And

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
      ...
    ],
    declarations: [AppComponent],
    providers: [
        {
            provide: UrlSerializer,
            useClass: LowerCaseUrlSerializer
        }
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

Comment: Does the second block of code show changes to your app.module?  I've tried this, and I get an error: Cannot read property 'serialize' of null.  Everything compiles correctly, and if I take the code back out, everything works properly.

Comment: Brian this is the exact way i use it even now without problems. Seems like it's not injecting the Serializer correctly. Serialize is a method of the DefaultSerializer - https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/api/router/index/DefaultUrlSerializer-class.html

Can you make a Plunker?

Comment: I have tried this again, and it works beautifully so far.  Not sure what was wrong the first time, but it seems to be working now.  Thanks so much.

Comment: I had to add the following import above the @NgModule:  import { UrlSerializer, DefaultUrlSerializer } from '@angular/router';

Comment: This doesn't work for me when using routerLink and I put some uppercase letters to it like routerLink="Home", though if I enter url path to browser directly like /Home it works

Comment: Important note: you should add it to the providers of your root app module  and to that module only(no point in adding it to the others)

Comment: A word of caution using this serialize, if you are adding any tokens such as identity tokens this will lowercase them causing them not to work correctly as the entire url is affected.

Comment: it's missing logic to handle url contains querystring parameters. I added the logic as following. 
        const urlParts = url.split('?');

        urlParts[0] = urlParts[0].toLowerCase();

        // If you lower it in the optional step
        // you don't need to use "toLowerCase"
        // when you pass it down to the next function
        return super.parse(urlParts.join('?'));

Comment: @Marko - I just discovered this problem myself. Did you find an alternative by chance?

Answer (score 11):

A little fix to [Timothy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46951813/1493081), which doesn't change the case of matched parameter names and values:

```
import {Route, UrlSegment, UrlSegmentGroup} from '@angular/router';

export function caseInsensitiveMatcher(url: string) {
  return function(
    segments: UrlSegment[],
    segmentGroup: UrlSegmentGroup,
    route: Route
  ) {
    const matchSegments = url.split('/');
    if (
      matchSegments.length > segments.length ||
      (matchSegments.length !== segments.length && route.pathMatch === 'full')
    ) {
      return null;
    }

    const consumed: UrlSegment[] = [];
    const posParams: {[name: string]: UrlSegment} = {};
    for (let index = 0; index < matchSegments.length; ++index) {
      const segment = segments[index].toString().toLowerCase();
      const matchSegment = matchSegments[index];

      if (matchSegment.startsWith(':')) {
        posParams[matchSegment.slice(1)] = segments[index];
        consumed.push(segments[index]);
      } else if (segment.toLowerCase() === matchSegment.toLowerCase()) {
        consumed.push(segments[index]);
      } else {
        return null;
      }
    }

    return { consumed, posParams };
  };
}
```

**Edit**: beside the problem explained above, there is another subtle bug which is resolved now. The for loop should iterate over `matchSegments` instead of `segments`.

Comment: This looks like a possible solution to my problem. I would like to try this in my angular app, by exporting this method in a shared.module.ts. Could that be then referenced in the app.module.ts? and any child module where I have child route configuration? I'm a typescript novice, so please pardon my ignorance.

Comment: @EakanGopalakrishnan you can either use it either in `RouterModule.forRoot(...)` as stated in [Timothy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46951813/1493081), or in a specific route definition.

Answer (score 8):

**update**

This didn't make it into the new router yet

**original**

Regex matchers were introduced recently. This might help for your use case.

See https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/7332/files

And this [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/mk8wPfoqS66Qsuu2yN4F?p=preview) from Brandon Roberts

```
@RouteConfig([
  { name : 'Test',
    //path : '/test',
    regex: '^(.+)/(.+)$', 
    serializer: (params) => new GeneratedUrl(`/${params.a}/${params.b}`, {c: params.c}),
    component: Test
//   useAsDefault: true
  }
])
```

Comment: Does regex matching for a predefined path has any advantages over `caseInsensitiveMatch: true` as suggested by someone on comments? Just asking because it works great without extra changes.

Comment: Haven't used any myself yet. Just remembered that this was introduced recently.  Where was `caseInsensitiveMatch: true` mentioned? Haven't seen this yet.

Comment: the comment was deleted.

Comment: I agree gunter, it looks like the caseInsensitiveMatch is part of the old router in angular2/router - the new router in @angular/router does not have this yet

Answer (score 7):

**Note:** The following works in Angular 4.x

I just use a matcher function:

```js
import { RouterModule, UrlSegment, UrlSegmentGroup, Route } from '@angular/router';

function CaseInsensitiveMatcher(url: string) {
    url = url.toLowerCase();

    return function(
        segments: UrlSegment[],
        segmentGroup: UrlSegmentGroup,
        route: Route
    ) {
        let matchSegments = url.split('/');
        if (
            matchSegments.length > segments.length ||
            (matchSegments.length !== segments.length && route.pathMatch === 'full')
        ) {
            return null;
        }

        let consumed: UrlSegment[] = [];
        let posParams: {[name: string]: UrlSegment} = {};
        for (let index = 0; index < segments.length; ++index) {
            let segment = segments[index].toString().toLowerCase();
            let matchSegment = matchSegments[index];

            if (matchSegment.startsWith(':')) {
                posParams[matchSegment.slice(1)] = segments[index];
                consumed.push(segments[index]);
            }
            else if (segment === matchSegment) {
                consumed.push(segments[index]);
            }
            else {
                return null;
            }
        }

        return { consumed, posParams };
    }
}
```

With:

```js
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        ...
        RouterModule.forRoot([
            { matcher: CaseInsensitiveMatcher('user/:id'), component: ProfileComponent },
        ])
    ],
    declarations: [
        ...
    ],
    bootstrap: [
        AppComponent
    ]
})
```

**Edit:** I just found out that in order to work with AoT compilation, the @NgModule portion would look more like this:

```js
export function profileMatch() {
    return CaseInsensitiveMatcher('user/:id').apply(this, arguments);
}

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        ...
        RouterModule.forRoot([
            { matcher: profileMatch, component: ProfileComponent },
        ])
    ],
    declarations: [
        ...
    ],
    bootstrap: [
        AppComponent
    ]
})
```

Comment: Thanks, it works, but it also converts parameter names and values to lower-case which may be troublesome. For example, if you are defining path as `users/:userId`, userId will be `undefined` in route. I added [a fix for this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47428947/1493081).

Comment: Hi, I see your answer and it's great, but how can we tell that AoT is or isn't working? I have attached more code to your/@AlirezaMirian 's answer, so I became curious of the impact.

Answer (score 6):

I did this in my app.component.ts:

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private _route: Router) { }
  public ngOnInit() {
    this._route.events.subscribe(event => {
      if (event instanceof NavigationStart) {
        let url = (<NavigationStart>event).url;
        if (url !== url.toLowerCase()) {
          this._route.navigateByUrl((<NavigationStart>event).url.toLowerCase());
        }
      }
    });
  }
}
```

and this is needed on router-link to make it active when selected:

```
<a routerLink="/heroes" routerLinkActive="active" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{ exact: false }">Heroes</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an updated version of `LowerCaseUrlSerializer` to not lowercase the query parameters.

```
import { DefaultUrlSerializer, UrlTree } from '@angular/router';

export class LowerCaseUrlSerializer extends DefaultUrlSerializer {
    parse(url: string): UrlTree {
      const path = url.split('?')[0];
      const query = url.split('?')[1] || '';
      return super.parse(path.toLowerCase() + (query !== '' ? `?${query}`: ''));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

My workaround for this issue:

```
/* IMPORTS */

let routeEntries = [
    { path: '/home', component: HomePage }
    /* DEFAULT ROUTE */
    { path: '/', component: HomePage },
    /* NOT FOUND ROUTE */
    { path: '*', component: HomePage }
];

@Component(/* SETUP */)
@Routes(routeEntries)

export App implements OnInit {
    /* STUFF */
    ngOnInit() {
        // subscribe to router changes
        this.router.changes.forEach(() => {
            let routerLink = location.pathname;
            let routerLinkLower = routerLink.toLowerCase();
            // if the route does not exist, check for the lowercase version
            if (!routeEntries.find((route) => { return route.path === routerLink; })) {
                this.router.navigate([routerLinkLower]);
            }
            // if the route is correct, set the active page
            else {
                // do something here if required
            }
        });
    }
}
```

This works with the RC1 router and goes along well with route variations, eg:

```
'{domain}:{port}/HoMe'
'{domain}:{port}/homE'
'{domain}:{port}/Home'
...
```

Comment: What happens to your route parameters? Do they get converted to lowercase as well?

Comment: Yeah, I didn't take those into account, routes aren't actually a problem in the application developed above to be honest, so I did not take that into account. So yes, sadly it seems to not cover all cases.