# angular 2 routeconfig case sensitivity

Tags: routes, angular, uppercase, angular2-routing

Lets say I have a route config like:

```
@RouteConfig([
    { path: '/login', name: 'Login', component: LoginPageContainer }
])
```

It is possible to subscribe to the router in angular 2 like the following:

```
   this.router.subscribe((nextValue) => {
       this.router.navigate(['nextValue']);
    });
```

In the given scenario next value will be all lowercase as in "login" rather than "Login". As the routeconfig defines the name with an upercase start the path will not resolve.

Is is possible to make the routeconfig name to be case-insensitive or is there a way to obtain the correctly cased name? I have been searching but am unable to find anything on this.

Comment: I've answered this question for RC1 here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37613743/6419372

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The `name` field is the route name which must be spelled in `PascalCase`
>   to avoid potential confusion with the route path.

If you wanted to go for workaround you could use `navigateByUrl` to have such thing to make it working. That method will take `Instruction`'s based on `URL` & then component associated with that route will get loaded.

```
this.router.subscribe((nextValue) => {
    this.router.navigateByUrl('/'+'nextValue');
});
```

Comment: Perfect, navigate by url worked spot on and was a perfect alternative for my needs. For the purpose of other viewers your code is slightly out and the call to redirect needs to be a forward slash to avoid escaping the chars:

this.router.navigateByUrl('/' + 'nextValue');

Comment: @CreativeAbyss updated thanks... but why you are doing in that way.. I'm still wondering about it..

Comment: In addition to returning false in the CanActivate() hook of my components I also subscribe to the router in my root component (app.ts) so that when the router changes url if a quick check to the authentication/session service shows the user is not authenticated I redirect to the login page.

Comment: @CreativeAbyss because the above way would become messy when you wanted to pass parameter with `route`..