# Making base url case insensitive with angular 2 router

Tags: angular

I have an application that does not get deployed at the root of our site, it lives at `site.com/TRAP_beta` and a component route defined like this `{ path: '', component: TrapFormComponent }`. I set the base url tag as `<base href="/TRAP_beta/">`.

When I navigate to `site.com/TRAP_beta` all is good with the world and the application works as intended, but if I navigate to `site.com/trap_beta` or any other cased version of the url, then router cannot find the path and it breaks.

How do I go about making the urls case insensitive to angular 2?

Comment: I answered a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41742651/base-href-is-case-sensitive-in-angular-2/51319920#51319920

Answer (score 1):

I ended up dynamically making the base element in a script tag that runs before anything else gets loaded.

```
    var path = location.pathname.substr(1).match(/[a-z_0-1]*/i)[0];
    var base = document.createElement('base');
    base.href = '/' + location.pathname.substr(1).match(/[a-z_0-1]*/i)[0] + '/';
    document.head.appendChild(base);
```

This seems to be resolving my issue and allowing me to continue to use `router.navigate` over `navigateByUrl`.

Comment: I did this: [http://stackoverflow.com/a/39737719/2071008](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39737719/2071008)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `router.navigateByUrl('/'+'nextValue');` instead of `router.navigate(['nextValue']);`.Because the instruction will be get based upon the URL provided.

Comment: What about the initial load of the application? The route with the path `''` doesn't even load if you don't go to `TRAP_beta` over any other variation.

Comment: I can't say much about with out looking into your code.Did you try to change the method  to navigatebyUrl where you tried to navigate explicitly

Comment: None of this was an issue with navigate links. The app itself threw an error before rendering a single component because it couldn't resolve any routes if the base url wasn't the same case sensitivity as what you put in.