# base href is case sensitive in Angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have set the base ref like this for an Angular 2 app

```
<base href="MyApp"/>
```

If I go to localhost/MyApp everything works correctly. However, if I go to localhost/myapp the route is not recognised. How can I tell Angular to treat the base route as case insensitive?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36154672/angular2-make-route-paths-case-insensitive have a look here

Comment: But again the best its to use lowercase to avoid all this problems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to write code to override base href.

Possible locations you can override is 
 1. [Angular2: Make route paths case insensitive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36154672/angular2-make-route-paths-case-insensitive)

2. You write your own location strategy & Ignore case sensitivity there. 
   And in your app.module.ts, you tell ur Angular 2 app to use custom location strategy in your providers section.

   {provide:LocationStrategy,useClass:CustomPlatformLocation},

Answer (score 0):

I tried Parth way, but I couldn't find a way to fix my problem with the `LocationStrategy` approach.

Based on some ideas from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36154672/angular2-make-route-paths-case-insensitive) and ended up with something like this:

```
import { DefaultUrlSerializer, UrlTree } from "@angular/router";

export class LowercaseUrlSerializer extends DefaultUrlSerializer {

    parse(url: string): UrlTree {

        let urlUpperBaseUrl = url;

        if (url.startsWith("/app")) {
            urlUpperBaseUrl = "/APP" + url.slice(4);
        }
        if (url.startsWith("app")) {
            urlUpperBaseUrl = "APP" + url.slice(3);
        }

        return super.parse(urlUpperBaseUrl);
    }

}
```

You have to configure the injector as well:

```
@NgModule({
    ...
    providers: [
        ...
        { provide: UrlSerializer, useClass: LowercaseUrlSerializer },
    ],
    ...
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

I hope it hepls!

Answer (score 0):

I added typed base href as a route in router config with redirectTo property set to default route of the app, which is in my case is 'login', so any combination of base href will work. This is more sort of a hack.

I wrote that code in the app.component.ts file.

```
ngOnInit() {
   var baseHref  = window.location.pathname.split('/')[1];
   if(baseHref != "" && baseHref != "login")
      this.router.config.Add({path:baseHref,redirectTo:'/login',pathMatch:'full'});
}
```

Note:- As suggested by other answers, LowerCaseUrlSerializer didn't work for me as it requires all routes specified in my app to be in lower case only.

Answer (score -1):

using `<base href="./">`
instead of `<base href="MyApp"/>` (implicit)
solved the problem for me.
the virtual directory now is case insensitive.

Comment: I suspect this only works because your site doesn't have any deep navigation URLs. If someone visited a deep link in your site (e.g. "MyApp/Admin/Configure"), this would set the base URL incorrectly (e.g. "MyApp/Admin").