# How to make base href / IIS virtual directory case insensitive for angular app?

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-router

There is similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41742651/base-href-is-case-sensitive-in-angular-2) without proper answer.

If I set in app.module.ts:

```
providers: [
  { provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: '/my/app'},
```

and type localhost:4200/my/app

```
this.location.path()
```

returns the correct path "".

However if I type localhost:4200/my/App

```
this.location.path()
```

returns "/my/App" which is wrong.

For reasons beyond this question I make checks for the URL. So my question is: how to make base href case insensitive?

I assume that installation on IIS fails for same reason.

Comment: Have you used LowerCaseUrlSerializer?

Comment: yes. it does not affect the base href

Comment: I think you need to change some setting on your iis

Comment: You could write an IIS rule that redirects to the lowercase version of your app. Alternatively, you could write a factory that provides `APP_BASE_HREF` at runtime to return the value currently in the url

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the best way may be to force IIS to redirect the user to `my/app` by using rewrite rules. However I don't know IIS, so I cannot give you a solution.

If you want to do it in angular, you could use the following code. It provides `APP_BASE_HREF` token dynamically with a factory

```
export function baseHrefFactory()
{
  let expectedBaseHref = '/my/app';
  let currentBaseHref = window.location.pathname.substr(0, expectedBaseHref.length);
  //Add checks herre if needed
  return currentBaseHref;
}

@NgModule({
/**/
  providers: [
    {provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useFactory: baseHrefFactory}
  ]
})
export class AppModule
```

Answer (score 0):

I loved @David's answer but I found my url ended up as /my/app/my/app when it was deployed and I have no idea why.  I altered his approach to redirect the user to the correct base href if the href was the same but a different case:

```
export function baseHrefFactory(): string {
  const expectedBaseHref = '/my/app';
  const currentBaseHref = window.location.pathname.substr(0, expectedBaseHref.length);
  if (expectedBaseHref.toLowerCase() === currentBaseHref.toLowerCase() && expectedBaseHref !== currentBaseHref)
  {
    // The two base hrefs are the same, but not the same case.
    // Redirect the user to the correct base href.
    const newLocation = window.location.href.replace(currentBaseHref, expectedBaseHref);
    window.location.replace(newLocation);
  }

  // this is the case for localhost (where we don't use a virtual directory)
  return currentBaseHref;
}

@NgModule({
/**/
  providers: [
    {provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useFactory: baseHrefFactory}
  ]
})
export class AppModule
```

Comment: thx for answer! however factory function does not return anything.

Comment: Apologies - I was sanitizing my code so I could post it and removed too much.  Now updated