# How to make virtual directory part of the URL in IIS case insensitive for the Angular app?

Tags: angular, iis

I know IIS is supposed to be case insensitive. However [angular app handles the base href part of the URL case sensitive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61056811/how-to-make-base-href-iis-virtual-directory-case-insensitive-for-angular-app) which means IIS should change the URL's base href-part to correct format before the angular app is involved.

So I have base href defined as:

```
myapp
```

and

```
import { Location } from '@angular/common';
// ...
private location: Location
```

With lots of trial and error with angular app I could not get

```
this.location.path()
```

to work properly with both URLS:

```
myapp/login
```

and

```
myApp/login
```

where myapp is the base href. The latter of the urls above is returned as myApp/login and not login by

```
this.location.path()
```

So I would like to create a rewrite rule in IIS that handles virtual directory / base href case insensitively and the angular app sees always urls like 'login' and not 'myApp/login'.

However IIS URL rewrite rules seem to be only for the part AFTER the virtual directory / base href.

What can I do? As I said, solving this in IIS only would be the best option. The other option where base href is handled in angular app might be possible but without hardcoding it in the app i was not able to get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

IIS is not case sensitive.you have to do the coding in the angular app. the only way you could try in is iis URL rewrite rule to convert URL in upper case or lower case. below is the sample rule:

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="LowerCaseRule1" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="([A-Z].*)" ignoreCase="false" />
            <action type="Redirect" url="{ToLower:{URL}}" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Comment: thanks, but this rule does nothing. 1st it matches only 1 letter, 2nd i don't think it handles the base href part at all.

Comment: it does not work. IIS says that Input for these rules are part of the url after the defined virtual directory.

Comment: @charm could you share snapshot which issue you are facing? you could also try to run failed request tracing in iis. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules

Comment: the issues i am facing is that http://localhost/MYAPP is not redirecting to http://localhost/myapp. please try it yourself and u'll find that it does nothing.

Comment: @charm please check this image at my side rule is working [image](https://i.imgur.com/Fy8oeAN.png)

Answer (score 0):

```
You may try the below rule to always lowercase the url if it is not **myapp**

<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="LowerCaseRule1" stopProcessing="true">
       <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny" trackAllCaptures="false">
           <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="/myapp" ignoreCase="false"  
           negate="true" />
           
        </conditions>
        <action type="Redirect" url="{ToLower:{URL}}"  />
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```