# angular 2 Routes 3.0, case sensitive

Tags: angular, typescript

```
const routes: Routes = [
 { path: 'x', component: xComponent }, 
 { path: 'y', component: yComponent }, 
 { path: 'zComponent', component: zComponent }
];
```

If I write in the url x small it will direct me to the component page, if I write X Capital it will say not valid url.

How to make the url insensitive Case

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39560520/1081079

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Two options ..
 1. create 1 URLSerializer Class

```
import { DefaultUrlSerializer, UrlTree } from '@angular/router';

export class LowerCaseUrlSerializer extends DefaultUrlSerializer {
    parse(url: string): UrlTree {
        return super.parse(url.toLowerCase());
    }
}
```

And in your app.module.ts

```
providers: [
        {
            provide: UrlSerializer,
            useClass: LowerCaseUrlSerializer
        }
    ],
```

Option 2:
Simple workaround in your route file.

```
{ path: '/home', redirectTo: ['/Home'] },
{ path: '/Home', component: HomeComponent, name: 'Home' },
```

Comment: 1st Option is the best I could Find. Because applies to route parameters too.

Comment: Important note for option 1: you should add it to your root app module providers and that module only.

Comment: Am Working on this for Seo Friendly URL Structure. Am trying to replace Slashes with Hyphens. While Routing its working perfect. But when Page reload Conflict is happening.. Any Idea..???