# Handle Routes with QueryParam in Angular2

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-cli, angular2-router

I have two routes in my appilcation

```
{path: 'activity/?cInfo=askjdfkajsdfkasd', component: PostComponent},
{path: 'activity/:id', component: PostDetailComponent}
```

What i have to do to make them work?

Route with querystring **?cInfo=askjdfkajsdfkasd** should go to **PostComponent**

and Route like **activity/skjdfhakjdfhaajsdf** should go to **PostDetailComponent**

i tried

```
{path: 'activity/?cInfo=askjdfkajsdfkasd', component: PostComponent,canActivate:[CheckForListPage],pathMatch:'full'},
{path: 'activity/:id', component: PostDetailComponent,canActivate:[CheckForDetailPage]}
```

but each time 1 is called. The guards are returning boolean.

Does angular differentiate between queryParams and pathVariables like most MVC do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you must declare your routes in this way.

```
{path: '/activity', component: PostComponent,canActivate:[CheckForListPage]},
{path: '/activity/:id', component: PostDetailComponent,canActivate:[CheckForDetailPage]}
```

So,  when you navigate to **/activity?cInfo=askjdfkajsdfkasd**  the router will match with the first defined route (/activity), and then you can retrieve the queryParameters passed to the route inside  the component **(PostComponent)**.

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.route.queryParams
        .subscribe(params => {
          // complete params object
          console.log(params);

          // your param passed 
          console.log(params['cInfo'])
        });
}
```

Of course you need import @angular/route ActivatedRoute

```
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
```

And set route in your constructor as a property of type **ActivatedRoute** before the first code snippet (which should be in ngOnInit method of your component class, which means your component class must implements OnInit from @angular/core).

```
constructor(
    private route     : ActivatedRoute
){}
```

Comment: any idea how to handle case senstivity?

Comment: @DinkarThakur What you mean exactly ? Something like this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36154672/angular2-make-route-paths-case-insensitive