# Angular 5: URLs case insensitive

Tags: angular, case-sensitive, angular-router

i know that this is common question but actually I didn't find any answer cover my needs...

I have an `angular5` app with route configuration like this:

```
const routes: Routes = [
{ path: 'businessaccountmanagement', component:BusinessAccountManagementComponent },
    ...
];
```

and according to [`UrlSerializer` documentation](https://angular.io/api/router/UrlSerializer) i've extends `DefaultUrlSerializer` like this:

```
import { DefaultUrlSerializer, UrlTree, UrlSerializer } from '@angular/router';

export class LowerCaseUrlSerializer extends DefaultUrlSerializer {
    parse(url: string): UrlTree {

        return super.parse(url.toLowerCase());
    }
}

export const LowerCaseUrlSerializerProvider = {
    provide: UrlSerializer,
    useClass: LowerCaseUrlSerializer
  };
```

So in this implementation everything is working fine coz all url cases will convert to lowercase and match with `path: 'businessaccountmanagement'`

But, what i need is to declare my route as `upper camel case` like this:

```
const routes: Routes = [
{ path: 'BusinessAccountManagement', component:BusinessAccountManagementComponent },
    ...
];
```

and accept all routes match the string regardless of letters case upper or lower

accepted routes example:

- domain/BusinessAccountManagement
- domain/businessaccountmanagement
- domain/BUSINESSACCOUNTMENEGEMENT
- ...

** The old version from my app was angular 1.x with [ui-route](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Quick-Reference)  and was able to do it in on line of code:

```
$urlMatcherFactory.caseInsensitive(true);
```

any help will be very appropriated.

Comment: Does that help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46951813/1392490

Comment: Thank you my friend, it helps.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular2: Make route paths case insensitive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36154672/angular2-make-route-paths-case-insensitive)