# Angular url case insensitive

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-ui-router

I'm new to angular. I have a question. localhost:4200/product working but localhost:4200/Product not working. I try;

```
import { DefaultUrlSerializer, UrlTree } from '@angular/router';

    export class LowerCaseUrlSerializer extends DefaultUrlSerializer {
        parse(url: string): UrlTree {
        return super.parse(url.toLowerCase()); 
        }
    }
    .

    .

    .


      providers: [
            {
                provide: UrlSerializer,
                useClass: LowerCaseUrlSerializer
            }
        ],
```

but make all the letters small. I want to all the links to work.

/product

/Product

/PRODUCT

/pRoDucT

......

app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { RouterModule, Route } from '@angular/router';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { ProductComponent } from './product/product.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';

const routeConfig: Route[] = [
{
  path: '',
  component: HomeComponent
},
{
  path: 'product',
  component:  ProductComponent
}
];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    ProductComponent,
    HomeComponent
],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule, FormsModule, RouterModule.forRoot(routeConfig)
  ],
  providers: [],
```

app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'Title';
}
```

I hope you understand. Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular2: Make route paths case insensitive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36154672/angular2-make-route-paths-case-insensitive)

Comment: I looked at that topic but I could not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should add this `provide` statement ,

```
providers: [
            {
                provide: UrlSerializer,
                useClass: LowerCaseUrlSerializer
            }
        ],
```

to the `app.module.ts` file. you have the providers empty in the app module.

Comment: the code works but I do not want all the letters to be small.

Comment: will this also Serialize the query parameters?

Comment: this will change the token in query string