# Angular 5 - how to use caseinsensitive code?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm getting an error on routeConfig.How can i fix this error.I do not know where to write the code.I'd be happy if you could write it in a descriptive way. Thank you.

[Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36154672/angular2-make-route-paths-case-insensitive/46951813#46951813)

app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

    @Component({
      selector: 'app-root',
      templateUrl: './app.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
    })
    export class AppComponent {
    }
```

app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { RouterModule, Route } from '@angular/router';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { ProductComponent } from './product/product.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';

const routeConfig: Route[] = [
{
  path: '',
  component: HomeComponent
},
{
  path: 'product',
  component:  ProductComponent
}
];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    ProductComponent,
    HomeComponent
],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule, FormsModule, RouterModule.forRoot(routeConfig)
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I did, Create separate class for Routing like this

```
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { Component } from './components';

const appRoutes: Routes = [
    { path: '', component: Component }
];

export const routing = RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes, { useHash: true });
```

Then import that routing class in module class like this,

```
import { routing } from './mymodule.routing';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        FormsModule,
        HttpModule,
        routing
    ],
declarations: [],
providers: [],
entryComponents: [],
exports: []
})
export class Module {
    constructor() {}
}
```