# Angular Route LazyLoading match the route prefix to load children

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-router

I am trying to do lazyloading for different modules and i am trying to match route prefix to load module. But it is not working, it works for exact url but not for prefix. i am using angular 6.1.

**this code does't work**

```
{
    path: 'account',
    component: AuthComponent,
    children: [
        {
            path: '',
            loadChildren: './modules/auth/auth.module#AuthModule'
        }
        {
            path: '**',
            loadChildren: './modules/auth/auth.module#AuthModule'
        }
    ]
},
```

**and this code works fine**

```
{
    path: 'account',
    component: AuthComponent,
    children: [
        {
            path: '',
            loadChildren: './modules/auth/auth.module#AuthModule'
        },
        {
            path: 'login',
            loadChildren: './modules/auth/auth.module#AuthModule'
        },
        {
            path: 'register',
            loadChildren: './modules/auth/auth.module#AuthModule'
        },
        {
            path: '**',
            loadChildren: './modules/auth/auth.module#AuthModule'
        }
    ]
},
```

Do i have to map each route for loading module?

**These are the routes i have in my module i am trying to load.**

```
const routes = [
{
    path: '',
    component: LoginComponent,
    data: {
        title: 'login'
    }
},
{
    path: 'login',
    component: LoginComponent,
    data: {
        title: 'login'
    }
},
{
    path: 'register',
    component: RegisterComponent,
    data: {
        title: 'register'
    }
},
{
    path: 'admin/login',
    component: LoginComponent,
    data: {
        title: 'Admin login'
    }
}
 ];
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: is repeating `./modules/auth/auth.module#AuthModule` for all routes a mistake? or are you trying to show an example?

Comment: @Yaser this is not the mistake, i tried ** for each module to just match the prefix, but it work for just that complete route, doesn't load the child routes.

Comment: do you have your code somewhere? stackblitz or similar?

Comment: @Yaser no sir, i want to load all routes for account, if route prefix is account.

Comment: @Yaser are these routes are case sensitive? i made route url's into small and that worked. that shouldn't happen

Comment: Have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36154672/angular2-make-route-paths-case-insensitive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this :

## MainModule

```
{
    path: 'account', loadChildren: './modules/auth/auth.module#AuthModule'
},
```

## AuthModuleRouting

```
const routes = [
{
    path: '', component: AuthComponent,
},
{
    path: 'login',
    component: LoginComponent,
    data: {
        title: 'login'
    }
},
{
    path: 'register',
    component: RegisterComponent,
    data: {
        title: 'register'
    }
},
{
    path: 'admin/login',
    component: LoginComponent,
    data: {
        title: 'Admin login'
    }
}
 ];
```

Comment: what if i directly enter the "admin/login" url? how module will be loaded and rout will be known?

Comment: If the complete url is `account/admin/login`, you shouldn't have a problem with that. The module should be loaded if you go on the `account` module, whatever the url you use.