# Angular route parameters changing to lowercase while passing Id of a firestore document

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angular8

What am trying to do is pass an Id of firestore collection document to route param so that it can show a detail page by using the id.

lets say the Id is 345GHl0833jkj
when its passed with the angular router it changes to 
http://localhost:4200/item/345ghl0833jkj

as you can see all are changed to lowercase

after taking the Id from the route param it requests the document with the id but, it won't get any result because firebase document is case sensitive.

How should I address the problem? Thank you.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36154672/angular2-make-route-paths-case-insensitive ??

Comment: those solution would work if we want the params to be in lowercase only, In my case the param can be like item/233HGJ45lkjh which has both uppercase and lowercase characters and firebase will only return result if you give it the exact id without changing its case. I don't have problem with the routing but, how the param is changed to lowercase, thanks.