# Error during template compile of 'AppRoutingModule' Function expressions are not supported in decorators

Tags: angular, routes, angular2-aot

I am using the "CaseInsensitiveMatcher" as [Alireza](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1493081/alireza-mirian) put up. Problem is when trying to do a prod build, I am getting the following error

> *"'urlMatch' references 'CaseInsensitiveMatcher'
>         'CaseInsensitiveMatcher' contains the error at src\app\providers\caseInsensitiveMatcher.ts(4,10)
>           Consider changing the function expression into an exported function"*

Sample Code from App Routing Module

```
    export function urlMatch(str: string) {
    return CaseInsensitiveMatcher(str).apply(this, arguments);
}

const routes: Routes = [

    { matcher: urlMatch('en-ie'), component: HomepageComponent },
    { matcher: urlMatch('en-gb'), component: HomepageComponent },
]

@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes),SharedModule, AccountModule],
    exports: [RouterModule, SharedModule, AccountModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

CaseInsensitveMatcher Code

```
import {Route, UrlSegment, UrlSegmentGroup} from '@angular/router';

export function CaseInsensitiveMatcher(url: string) {
  return function(
    segments: UrlSegment[],
    segmentGroup: UrlSegmentGroup,
    route: Route
  ) {
    const matchSegments = url.split('/');
    if (
      matchSegments.length > segments.length ||
      (matchSegments.length !== segments.length && route.pathMatch === 'full')
    ) {
      return null;
    }

    const consumed: UrlSegment[] = [];
    const posParams: {[name: string]: UrlSegment} = {};
    for (let index = 0; index < matchSegments.length; ++index) {
      const segment = segments[index].toString().toLowerCase();
      const matchSegment = matchSegments[index];

      if (matchSegment.startsWith(':')) {
        posParams[matchSegment.slice(1)] = segments[index];
        consumed.push(segments[index]);
      } else if (segment.toLowerCase() === matchSegment.toLowerCase()) {
        consumed.push(segments[index]);
      } else {
        return null;
      }
    }

    return { consumed, posParams };
  };
}
```

I would greatly appreciate if anyone could tell me what I am doing wrong with this? or even how to resolve it. Either way thanks for thanking the time to read

[Link To Orginal for Context](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47428947/2425561)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CaseInsensitveMatcher returns an anonymous function, but unfortunately Angular does not allow dynamic code like this in AOT. What you can do is to rework your solution so that you only use named exported functions without involving anonymous ones.

Comment: To sound cheeky, can you send me a link on how to this or provide a solution. Thanks

Comment: I'll send you a stack blitz link

Comment: user2425561 as sad as this may seem that you need to create a function per each case, it compiles in AOT, so at least it will work. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-p8fbrl?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp-routing.module.ts

Comment: Worked like a charm, thank you very much.  Annoying to do it for all routes, but beggars can't be choosers. Thanks again