# Navigate to specific page (not to root page) by manually entering its URL in browser in Angular app and avoid error 404 (IIS)

Tags: angular, iis, angular2-routing, single-page-application

So, my problem is as indicated in the title. I have read some articles in Internet and still cannot sort the things out.

I use IIS and host Angular app on it.

If I use simple redirection rule in **web.config** that is suggested in internet - I'm redirected to 'root' page, that is not what I want: I want to be redirected to the page that is requested. Is some more fancy redirection rule needed and that will do it?

If I use hash strategy - the redirection seems to work ok, but it's CASE-SENSITIVE. I want it to be case-insensitive.

Please suggest the solution or the link where I can read in details about it (I've tried Angular.io and have not found the suitable approach there either).

Current redirection rules:

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true" />
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="AngularJS Routes" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url=".*" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/(api)" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="/CentralTools" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

And when I try to navigate to - let's say - https://xxx.yyy.cloudapp.azure.com/CentralTools/licences - I'm redirected to https://xxx.yyy.cloudapp.azure.com/CentralTools/ (root page). If it's relevant, the app base url is "`base href="/CentralTools/`"

Comment: am not sure if this can help you but you can check it out
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36154672/angular2-make-route-paths-case-insensitive/37613743

Comment: Don’t use hash, it’s far from ideal. You need to setup your web.config so all requests to a non-existing resource are  rewritten to index.html

Comment: @mikeone what about existing resources? I'd like all requests to existing pages to be routed properly. At least, hash + LowerCaseUrlSerializer suggested by abdelmlak-dhif above do it work properly... But of course I will switch to rewrite once I figure out how to make it right (to redirect to the asked page (if it exists) - not to root page).

Comment: The routes you have in your angular application are non-existing resources on your server don’t forget..  angular takes care of those routes in the browser. However if you refresh such a route, it goes to the server.. which can’t find that route.. rewrites it to index.html (which is your angular app) and angular goes to the correct path in your app again.

Comment: @mikeone aha, things are getting more clear now... But then I suppose I have some issue with redirection rules. Because when I use it and enter some route within my Angular app - I'm redirected to root page, not this specific page... I will update my question with the corresponding additional info.

Comment: @mikeone I've updated the question with the info about redirection rules I'm trying to use.

Comment: You shouldn’t redirect, you should rewrite. So suppose in Angular you have a route localhost/myroute, the server should serve /index.html for that path (as it doesn’t exist on the server).. angular boots, and show the component for /myroute.. and that is what you want I think?

Comment: @mikeone  Uhm... I feel confused :) I say "redirected", because it looks like this from user's point of view. But actually the rule in web.config says "Rewrite". And I do have index.html in the root folder after building Angular app. CentralTools - base url - is a folder which contains my Angular app. And this is served as a web application (with the same name) in IIS.

Comment: From your example urls it does look like a redirect (the url is changing?).. the server should not change the url (i.e NOT sent a 301/302) but simply serve another resource (/CentralTools/index.html) when /CentralTools/license is requested

Comment: @mikeone Thank you - I will be able to check a couple of days later, because meanwhile lost connection to servers. Possibly talk to you later.

Comment: I checked your url rule and it seems there is a problem, about how to troubleshoot the url rewrite, you can try to use [failed request tracking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis). If you still can't solve the problem, please post more details information about your requirement, I can give you a demo for reference.

Comment: @samwu thanks for the suggestion - I will keep this bookmarked. But for the moment, rewrite rule - as suggested by MikeOne - works

Comment: @mikeone Seems like adding index.html did the trick. Thank you for your help and making things clear for me - suddenly some mist has gone from my head :)